# DDE print fails on Windows 2008

Tags: ms-word, windows-services, dde, local-system-account

I have a Windows Service application (developed in C++) running under Local System account. Operating system is Windows Server 2008 Standard - Service Pack 2 - 32-bit - 4Gb RAM. 
Also running Office 2003 with Service Pack 3.

This service takes a RTF file and using DDE prints it with Microsoft Word. However Word fails to perform the print issuing an error (I can see the error if I enable interaction with desktop). The error is

"Run-time error '1001':

There is insufficient memory. Save the document now.
C:...\file.rtf"

A screenshot can be seen here: http://img804.imageshack.us/img804/9550/worderror.png

It used to work on Windows 2003.

Any idea? Suggestions? Could be permission related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually not supported by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757